# print preview doesn't show barcode

Tags: .net, printing

When I write to the windows form directly it looks fine, when I print to the printer from the print preview it looks fine. However the print preview itself is not rendering the barcode text with the barcode font.

```
Public Class frmPrintPreview
Private Const testString1 As String = "*A1C1S1B1*"
Private Const testString2 As String = "*A99C99S7B3*"
Dim _BarcodeFont As System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection
Dim _BarcodeFont1 As Font
Dim _BarcodeFont2 As Font
Private Sub frmPrintPreview_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    _BarcodeFont = New System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection()
    _BarcodeFont.AddFontFile("FRE3OF9X.TTF")
    _BarcodeFont.AddFontFile("FREE3OF9.TTF")
    _BarcodeFont1 = New Font(Me._BarcodeFont.Families(0), 20, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)
    _BarcodeFont2 = New Font(Me._BarcodeFont.Families(1), 20, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)
End Sub



Private Sub PrintData(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    DrawingRoutine(e.Graphics)
End Sub

Private Sub DrawingRoutine(ByRef g As Graphics)
    Dim PrintFont As Font
    PrintFont = New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, 10.0, FontStyle.Regular) ', GraphicsUnit.Point)
    g.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
    Dim y As Int32 = 0
    g.DrawString(vbCrLf + Application.ProductName + " Version:" _
                           + Application.ProductVersion + vbCrLf _
                           + testString1, PrintFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0)
    y += 80
    g.DrawString(testString1, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 50, y)
    y += 40
    g.DrawString(testString1, _BarcodeFont1, Brushes.Black, 50, y)
    y += 40
    g.DrawString(testString2, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 50, y)
    y += 40
    g.DrawString(testString2, _BarcodeFont2, Brushes.Black, 50, y)

End Sub

Private Sub btnPrint_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    DrawingRoutine(e.Graphics)
End Sub


Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    Using printPreview As New PrintPreviewDialog()
        Dim x As New Printing.PrintDocument()
        AddHandler x.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintData
        printPreview.Document = x
        Dim result As DialogResult = printPreview.ShowDialog(Me)
        ' MsgBox(result)

    End Using
End Sub
```

End Class

what is wrong with  my print preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printer either had the fonts or my printing method made graphics out of them on the way to both the printers I tried printing on.  Once I installed those fonts to the computer I was on, Printpreview worked also.